# I am married to a UK citizen. What type of visa do I need to travel to the UK for tourism?

Tags: visas, uk, uk-citizens, spouses, bangladeshi-citizens

I am a Bangladeshi citizen married with my husband who is a British citizen by birth. Currently, we both live in Bangladesh and my husband works at a university. We, are planning to visit UK for about 3 weeks. Just to be clear, we have no intention to settle down in the UK.

*Do I need to apply for a visa? If so, then what type of visa should I apply for?*

N.B. I've been searching on the internet (including the UK border agency website) for hours now but couldn't get a definite answer.

Comment: Good question, five minutes of googling shows that it's not easy to find information on this (difficult to filter out irrelevant results). Personally I would probably just ask the British High Commission in Dhaka. Although I'm sure someone here at TSE are probably going to know as well.

Comment: @GayotFow You'd have to know about the wizard first, which I didn't.

Comment: @GayotFow Presumably, the reason for the close votes is that more clarification is required from OP? Isn't that needed before answering? Or is it possible to write a split answer with each part assuming one scenario?

Comment: @GayotFow If this is currently answerable, why did you vote to close as unclear? By the way, I don't have time to answer this at the moment.

Answer (score 5):

The UKVI tool says that, as a Bangladeshi citizen visiting the UK for tourism, [you need to apply for a Standard Visitor Visa](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/bangladesh/tourism):

[image]

When applying for a [Standard Visitor Visa](https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa) you will most probably be asked to provide details of your trip, as well as proof of funds, and proof of strong ties to your country of origin. That is when you will mention that your husband is a UK citizen.